# Confusion about Satisfiability by a denumerable sequence.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In "Introduction to Mathematical logic" by Elliot Mendelson , page $59$ . I couldn't understand the basic preliminary notations for the rigorous definition of Satisfiability.

For example , at a line they said,

"*Moreover, instead of talking about the
$n$-tuples of objects that satisfy a wf that has $n$ free variables, it is much more
convenient from a technical standpoint to deal uniformly with denumerable
sequences. What we have in mind is that a denumerable sequence
$s = (s_1, s_2 , s_3 , ... )$ is to be thought of as satisfying a wf $\beta$ that has
${x_j}_1 , {x_j}_2 ,  ... , {x_j}_n$ as free variables (where $j_1 < j_2 < ... < j_n$ ) if the $n$-tuple
$\langle {s_j}_1 , {s_j}_2 ,  ... , {s_j}_n \rangle$ satisfies $\mathscr B$ in the usual sense.*"

I didn't quite understand why they used ${s_j}_1$ and ${x_j}_1$ instead of $s_1$ and $x_1$ . Maybe there is a critical detail I am missing out?

Also , Another passage for the rigorous definition:

"*Let $M$ be an interpretation of a language $\mathscr L$ and let $D$ be the domain of
$M$. Let $\sum$ be the set of all denumerable sequences of elements of $D$. For a wf
$\mathscr B$ of $\mathscr L$ , we shall define what it means for a sequences $s= (s_1, s_2, ... )$ in $\mathscr L$ to
satisfy $\mathscr B$ in $M$. As a preliminary step, for a given s in $\sum$ we shall define a
functions $s^*$ that assigns to each term $t$ of $\mathscr L$ an element $s^{*}(t)$ in $D$.*"

They did say that for each $s = (s_1, s_2, ... )$ , there is a defined function $s^*$ , but even after further reading the text afterwards , I still did not understand how exactly $s^*$ is defined from $s$ . Can someone tell me where the gap in my understanding here is?

Comment: The variable are ordered: $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ but there is not a requirement to use them  in a formula in that order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *denumerable* sequence is a function $s: \text {Var} \to D$, where $\text {Var}$ is the ordered list of variables of the language: $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ and $D$ is the domain of the interpretation.

What is e.g. $s(x_1)$? It is an element $d \in D$ such that: $s(x_1)=d$, and so on.

This function "induces" a function $s^* : \text {Term} \to D$ that assigns a reference to each *term* $t$ of the language, according to the following rule:

(i) if $t$ is a variable $x_i$, then $s^*(t)=s(x_i)$; as we know already, it is an element of $D$.

(ii) if $t$ is a *constant* symbol $c$, then its reference is fixed by the interpretation, i.e. an element $c^D \in D$. Thus: $s^*(c)=c^D$.

What is left?

The case (iii) with a compound term $f_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.
In this case, we use the $n$-ary function $f_n^D$ on the domain $D$ assigned to the symbol $f_n$ by the interpretation, and we use $s$ to assign reference to the variable. Thus: $s^*[f_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)]=f_n^D(s(x_1),\ldots,s(x_n))$.

Consider a simple example with the language of arithmetic, where the symbol $+$ is a binary function symbol, interpreted in the domain $D$ of *natural* numbers ($\mathbb N$) with the usual *sum*.

Let $s(x_1)=1$ and $s(x_2)=2$, and let $t$ the term: $+(x_1,x_2)$.

We have:

> $s^*[+(x_1,x_2)]=+^D(1,2)=1+2$.

---

Regarding the first question, there is no "deep meaning".

The author is suggesting that the definition of *satisfaction* in terms of denumerable sequences (due originally to [Alfred Tarski (1936)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/tarski-truth/#StaTruDef)) is equivalent to the definition in terms of $n$-tuples currently used in [model theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/modeltheory-fo/#Lang).

Consider a simple example with as $\mathscr B$ the formula: $\forall x_1 (x_1 < x_2)$.

In this case, the free variable in the formula is $x_2$ and thus what is relevant for the satisfaction of the formula by a sequence $s$ is the object assigned by $s$ to $x_2$.

Thus, the first quote above means: we have a *denumerable* sequence $s= (s_1,s_2,s_3,\ldots)$, that means a function: $s(x_1)=s_1, s(x_2)=s_2 \in D$, and so on.

We have that, regarding satisfiability, it is the same to consider the "full" sequence or the $n$-uple extracted from the sequence considering only the free variables occurring into $\mathscr B$: in this case: $⟨s_2⟩$.

Comment: This answered my second question nicely. But I am still in the dark on the first question.Why did they use j1 , j2 , j3 , ... , jn instead of 1 , 2 ,3 ,4 .Because they already stated that j1 , j2 , ... , jn . So , the only possible values are , j1 = 1 ; j2 = 2  , j3 =3 and so on . It seems to me that adding j1 , j2 as subscripts is unnecessary . Can you analyze why we have to use those kinds of subscripts ?

Comment: "The only possible values are, $j_1=1$, $j_2 = 2$, $j_3 = 3$ and so on." No, that's not the case. For example, we might have a formula $\forall x_{37}\, (R(x_{37},x_{89}) \lor R(x_{37},x_{42}))$. The free variables in this formula are $x_{42}$ and $x_{89}$, so we can write it as $\varphi(x_{j_1},x_{j_2})$ where $j_1 = 42$ and $j_2 = 89$. The point of requiring $j_1 < j_2 < \dots$ is just for consistency: once we have identified the free variables of a formula, we know in which order to write them down.