# What is the purpose of double subscripts in variables in first order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In "Introduction to Mathematical logic" by Elliot Mendelson , page $50$ and $56$ . I couldn't understand why they sometimes use double subscripts .

For example , in page $50$ :

> "We shall often indicate that some of the variables $x_{i_1},..., x_{i_k}$  are free variables
> in a wf $\mathscr B$ by writing $\mathscr B$ as $\mathscr B(x_{i_1},..., x_{i_k} )$ This does not mean that $\mathscr B$
> contains these variables as free variables, nor does it mean that $\mathscr B$ does not
> contain other free variables. This notation is convenient because we can then
> agree to write as $\mathscr B(t_1,..., t_k)$ the result of substituting in $\mathscr B$ the terms $t_1,..., t_k$
> for all free occurrences (if any) of $x_{i_1} , ... , x_{i_k}$ respectively."

Here , I didn't understand why they used double subscript notation in $x_{i_1},..., x_{i_k}$ instead of single subscript notation like in $\mathscr B(t_1,..., t_k)$ .

In page $56$ :

> "Moreover, instead of talking about the
> $n$-tuples of objects that satisfy a wf that has $n$ free variables, it is much more
> convenient from a technical standpoint to deal uniformly with denumerable
> sequences. What we have in mind is that a denumerable sequence
> $s = (s_1, s_2 , s_3 , ... )$ is to be thought of as satisfying a wf $\mathscr B$  that has
> ${x_j}_1 , {x_j}_2 ,  ... , {x_j}_n$ as free variables (where $j_1 < j_2 < ... < j_n$ ) if the $n$-tuple
> $\langle {s_j}_1 , {s_j}_2 ,  ... , {s_j}_n \rangle$ satisfies $\mathscr B$ in the usual sense."

Again , they used Double subscript notation in ${x_j}_1 , {x_j}_2 ,  ... , {x_j}_n$ but also there is this condition $j_1 < j_2 < ... < j_n$ . This just adds to the confusion to me because I don't understand at all why do they use Double subscript in the first place (To the point that it seems completely unnecessary.

Now , I am completely new to subjects like first order logic and model theory , so I might struggle sometimes with the significance of some notation which actually has a good technical reason for using.This might be the case for this one as well.Can someone tell me the deep technical reason why we use double subscript sometimes below variables? (It could be possible that there are multiple reasons)

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3942987/confusion-about-satisfiability-by-a-denumerable-sequence)

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice. If you have more to add to clarify your previous question, you can edit it.